# CheckboxGroup, bokeh, stacked bar chart

Tags: python, bokeh, stacked-chart, user-interaction

I have made a stacked bar chart in bokeh with a hover tool and now also wants to add a `CheckboxGroup` to the plot. I am however very new to Bokeh, so I am struggeling a bit. I am especially unsure about how to make the update function, I have tried to start it but simply don't understand what it needs to do:

```
    trees_to_plot = [tree_selection.labels[i] for i in 
                        tree_selection.active]
    temp = make_dataset(trees_to_plot,
                           bin_width = 40)
    # \TODO: add more code here!
```

The code for the chart itself looks like this:

```
p = figure(x_range = districtName,plot_width = 900, plot_height=400, 
           title='Tree pr. district',toolbar_location= None)
# Stacked bar chart
renderers = p.vbar_stack(stackers=treeName,x='bydelsnavn',source=temp,
            width=0.5, color = colornames)

# Add the hover tool
for r in renderers:
    tree = r.name
    hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[
        ("%s" % tree, "@{%s}" % tree)
    ], renderers = [r])
    p.add_tools(hover)

p.xaxis.axis_label = 'Copenhagen city cistricts'
p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Tree counts'

# Creat the checkbox selection element
tree_selection = CheckboxGroup(labels=treeName, active = [0,1])
# Link the checkboxes to the information on the graph
tree_selection.on_change('active', update)

# Add to the CheckboxGroup to the figure
controls = WidgetBox(tree_selection)
layout = row(controls,p)
show(layout)
```

This code will show all the check boxes with the chart but no interaction is obviously happening between the boxes and the chart itself. Can someone point me towards to right direction?

Thanks in advance! :D

Answer (score 0):

You're using `show` which creates a static HTML page. But to `on_change`, you pass a Python function, and for that to work you need to use a Bokeh server. Try follow this example: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#single-module-format
If it still doesn't work, make sure to post the complete code that can be run without any modifications.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! :-)

I have tried to follow the section about 'Building Bokeh Applications' as I eventually will have to combine two different visualizations (a map and the stackedBarchart) and make them interact with eachother (so when I push one bar of the stackedBarchart I want the map to follow this). Am I understanding it correclyt or is there another way than building an application? It sounds a bit complicated

Comment: It's not complicated at all! In simple cases, you can just replace `show` with `curdoc().add_root` and run it using `bokeh serve` instead of `python`.

Comment: I see, I think I miss understood! What do you excatly mean by running it using bokeh serve? 
I am currently using a Jupyter Notebook environment.

Comment: I have tried to simply copy the code in the link you sent and to try and see how it works but I cannot figure out to execute the following: 'bokeh serve --show myapp.py'.

Comment: You have to have some command line available. There, you have to have the correct Python virtual environment active (if any) - Bokeh should be installed there. And then you can just type that `bokeh serve` command there, just make sure you do that in the directory with `myapp.py`.